# Calculating probability of guessing objective choices

Tags: probability

There is a competitive exam IIT-Jee conducted every year in India attempted by I guess 1.2 million 12th grade students for Engineering degree seats in reputed government backed institutes.

My daughter left unanswered 30 questions out of 225. To me it looked winning strategy to even randomly select any choice instead of leaving them unanswered. I wondered how many marks she would have got as per probability had she not left them unanswered. A tutor who has been teaching Maths(including probability) himself not sure of this and instead advised me that the right thing is to "*select answer only if one is sure*" -- did not go down well to me.

I couldn't solve this so I've come here to get answer to this question:

**Each question consists of 4 choices and correct answer gets 4 marks while wrong one -1.**

Given that there are 30 questions whose choices one'd click blindly... what is the probability that one will  get 0 or more marks?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific dififculties you are encountering.  Please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: The number of questions does not matter. Clearly the expectation of marks per questions is $0$ so in expectation you get $0$ on the test.Though, having a negative grade to a test is usually impossible, you just get $0$. So the expectation of the grade is positive.

Answer (score 1):

It's beyond me to get into generalized solution with given set of questions **n**.

I wrote simple program(in PHP) and did some iterations and I found this result:
[image]

**Explanation**

- A = Total Questions tried
- B = Probability of getting less than 0 when each question is tried with correct/incorrect combination
- C = Total combinations( eg Two question - 1st can be correct/incorrect; 2nd too resulting in 4 combinations
- D = Out of total of C combinations, each totaled how many resulted in negative marks total for C combinations

If only two questions are there:

- 1st Question:  Can result in being incorrect or correct
- 2nd Question:  Can result in being incorrect or correct

Assume 0=incorrect and 1=correct. Mind you correct gets 4 marks and incorrect -1.

We get 4 combinations:

[image]

**PHP Code**

```
<?php

$map=array();

for($i=0;$i<2;++$i)
for($j=0;$j<2;++$j)
for($k=0;$k<2;++$k)
{
        $str="A{$i}B{$j}C{$k}";

        $marks =  (($i==0)?-1:4)  + (($j==0)?-1:4)  +  (($k==0)?-1:4)

                ;

        $map[$str]=$marks;

}


print_r($map);

$negative=0;

foreach($map as $key=>$val)
{

        if($val<0) ++$negative;


}
print("Total combinations = ".(count($map))." Total negative=".$negative."\n");

print("Total negative=1/".(round(count($map)/$negative,1))."\n");
```

**Result**
[image]

Comment: Yes for set of 30 questions tried, it does not. But I  tried simulating if tried questions are from 2-18 calculating the probabilities of getting negative marks using random selection.  I have verified manually that the answer if n=2 or n=3 is really correct and not sure of beyond that